# How can I remove the white characters from configuration file?

Tags: python, configparser

I would like to modify the samba configuration file using python.
This is my code

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read( '/etc/samba/smb.conf' )

for section in parser.sections():
    print section
    for name, value in parser.items( section ):
        print '  %s = %r' % ( name, value )
```

but the configuration file contains tab, is there any possibility to ignore the tabs?

```
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /etc/samba/smb.conf
    [line 38]: '\tworkgroup = WORKGROUP\n'
```

Comment: You can `.strip()` the strings, which will remove the tabs too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

data = StringIO('\n'.join(line.strip() for line in open('/etc/samba/smb.conf')))

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.readfp(data)
...
```

Another way (thank @mgilson for idea):

```
class stripfile(file):
    def readline(self):
        return super(FileStripper, self).readline().strip()

parser = SafeConfigParser()
with stripfile('/path/to/file') as f:
    parser.readfp(f)
```

Comment: I thought about inheriting from `file` too, but I'm always hesitant since the docs say you should use `open` to construct `file` objects -- but I never quite understood why.

Comment: @mgilson, I think because this approach does not allow to pass `StringIO` or other file-like object in the my `stripfile`. If your class constructor taking file, not the filename, this would be possible and it's so good. But for everyday tasks it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a small proxy class to feed the parser:

```
class FileStripper(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.fileobj = open(f)
        self.data = ( x.strip() for x in self.fileobj )
    def readline(self):
        return next(self.data)
    def close(self):
        self.fileobj.close()

parser = SafeConfigParser()
f = FileStripper(yourconfigfile)
parser.readfp(f)
f.close()
```

You might even be able to do a little better (allow for multiple files, automagically close when you're finished with them, etc):

```
class FileStripper(object):
    def __init__(self,*fnames):
        def _line_yielder(filenames):
            for fname in filenames:
                with open(fname) as f:
                     for line in f:
                         yield line.strip()
        self.data = _line_yielder(fnames)

    def readline(self):
        return next(self.data)
```

It can be used like this:

```
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.readfp( FileStripper(yourconfigfile1,yourconfigfile2) )
#parser.readfp( FileStripper(yourconfigfile) ) #this would work too
#No need to close anything :).  Horray Context managers!
```

Comment: If you make `readline` a generator (with `yield`), you don't have to load the whole file into `self.data`.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone -- I made `self.data` a generator, so I'm not reading the whole file.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: It doesn't. `self.data` is a generator.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone -- Really, since these are config files, they're not likely to be big enough to matter and the answer by defuz is likely to be easier to implement.  I just thought I would show one way to do it without reading the whole file at once.