# How to stop Python 2.7 RawConfigParser throwing ParsingError on tabs?

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, tabs, python-3.3

I am writing a package compatible with both `Python 2.7.13` and `Python 3.3`, and using the following:

```
try:
    import configparser
except:
    from six.moves import configparser
```

But when I load my `.gitmodules` file on `Python 2.7`:

```
    configParser   = configparser.RawConfigParser( allow_no_value=True )
    configFilePath = os.path.join( current_directory, '.gitmodules' )

    configParser.read( configFilePath )
```

It throw the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "update.py", line 122, in run
    self.create_backstroke_pulls()
  File "update.py", line 132, in create_backstroke_pulls
    configParser.read( configFilePath )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
    raise e
ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /cygdrive/d/.gitmodules
        [line  2]: '\tpath = .versioning\n'
        [line  3]: '\turl = https://github.com/user/repo\n'
```

But if I remove the tabs from the `.gitmodules` file, it works correctly. On `Python 3.3` it does work with tabs, only on `Python 2.7.13` it is not working with tabs. How can I make it work without removing the tabs?

The tabs are natively put by `git` when I am adding new submodules, so I definitely not remove them from the original file. I have been thinking I could duplicate the file, while removing the tabs. But is there less costly operation for compatibility with `Python`?

---

Related questions:

1. [How can I remove the white characters from configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821946/how-can-i-remove-the-white-characters-from-configuration-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be to use a `io.StringIO`, with modified contents, to pass to `readfp` (which accepts a file handle instead of file name).

The following code is trying to comply to both Python 2 and Python 3 (even if in python 3, `readfp` is deprecated, now it's `read_file`. Anyway that still works). Note that I don't need `six` package, `configparser` exists natively in 2 & 3 python versions.

```
try:
    import ConfigParser as configparser
except ImportError:
    import configparser

import io
try:
    unicode
except NameError:
    unicode = str  # python 3: no more unicode

r = configparser.RawConfigParser()

with open(configFilePath) as f:
    fakefile = io.StringIO(unicode(f.read().replace("\t","")))

r.readfp(fakefile,filename=configFilePath)
```

so the parser is "fooled" by reading a fake file with filecontents minus the tabs.

Comment: It is throwing this error `fakefile = io.StringIO(f.read().replace("\t",""))
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: I also tried to change `"\t",""` to `u"\t",u""` and it also worked. 1. [TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720919/typeerror-initial-value-must-be-unicode-or-none-not-str) 2. [How can I resolve TypeError with StringIO in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316333/how-can-i-resolve-typeerror-with-stringio-in-python-2-7)